# Microsoft Search Server programming issue

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008, search-server

I am using Microsoft Search Server 2008 based on SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to know whether there are any ways (some open API or web services or some hacking ways) to retrieved the crawled page content? The crawl source is web site.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "crawled content"? It sounds like you want to know if crawled content is stored in MS Search Server? If so, it is not.

Although I do not know how MSS's inner algorithms etc. work, it is based on MOSS's search which in turn uses *["a tuned version of the engine in MS Desktop Search"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_Server)*. Only an index is stored in the search server.

More on how indexing in MOSS (and thusly MSS) works can be found **[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.search.aspx)**.

Comment: "If so, it is not." -- do you have any documents to prove?